# Outlook smtp/exchange behavior differences

Tags: c#, email, outlook, smtp, exchange-server

I have implemented using SMTP an automatic email to be sent to a users outlook inbox. A calendar appointment is sent at the same time using an alternate view. There is also a html icon which can be double clicked to open the html file in a browser. I am now using identical code but with an exchange server and am having different results. The behavior is different while still using the same code! Are there some features that are blocked while using exchange? How can I get around this problem and achieve the same results?

**Screenshot using just SMTP:**

[image]

**Code using just SMTP:**

```
//Message

MailMessage msg  = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("from@test.com");
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@test.com"));
mailMessage.Subject = "Subject";



//Calendar

System.Net.Mime.ContentType ctCal = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
ctCal.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
AlternateView calendarView =
AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(GetCalendarEvent(mailMessage, "Test",
"REQUEST", strReviewByDate, strReviewByDate, "").ToString(), ctCal);
mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(calendarView);



//Read Html file.

String filePath =  "C:\\Path\\To\\File.html";
StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(strFilePath);
String body = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
sr.Close();


//I make other changes to the html file here//


//Save Html file

FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite("C:\\Path\\To\\EditedFile.html");
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8);   
writer.Write(strBody);
writer.Close();


//Add Attachment to message

mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\\Path\\To\\EditedFile.html"));


//Send the email

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1", 25);
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

**Screenshot after changing to use with Exchange:**

[image]

**Code change to use with Exchange:**

The only code changed from the above code to use with exchange is on the following line:

```
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("exchange.test.example.com", 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

The iCal must be the one and only MIME part in the message.
If you want an attachment, it must be added to the iCal MIME part (ATTACH header).